# Why doesn't my Win10 laptop automatically connect to my iPhone hotspot?

Tags: windows-10, iphone, wifi-configuration, mobile-hotspot

I have a laptop running Win10 and an iPhone 6.  My home internet connection often disconnects due to a problem with the ISP (they're working on it). But I have my iPhone hotspot on all the time and my PC wifi is setup with the "connect automatically" box checked for the hotspot--but when I get disconnected from my ISP, the laptop never automatically switches to the iPhone.  Why not and can I fix that?

Comment: It may connect automatically to other saved APs if and only if it actually disconnects. "spotty and often drops" doesn't mean it disconnect from that AP. It's worth troubleshooting but that would be a different question.

Comment: I'm not sure what AP means, but I revised my question to clarify that I am getting disconnected.

Comment: AP -> Access Point, i.e., a wireless network. It doesn't matter what happens with your internet service. It matters whether the computer is still connected to the router's WiFi. As long as it stays connected to one AP, regardless of the it having internet access or not, it won't connect to different one automatically, this is my point since the beginning.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  Is there anything that can be done to change that? Maybe software that will automatically disconnect from the router's WiFi if the internet access is lost?

Comment: This may or may not work: https://www.howto-connect.com/automatically-switch-to-strongest-wifi-windows-10/ It's designed to connect to the strongest signal AP, not for your specific situation. If your home AP keeps a stronger WiFi signal than the alternative you want to connect to then this won't work obviously. You'd need something that constantly pings a known site and if it fails disconnect and reconnect to another AP. AFAIK there's no such thing already available but it certainly can be coded.